# CSS Animation for SVG doesn't work in Mozilla

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG displayed on my webpage. I declared an animation to animate it. It works fine on Chrome but it doesn't work on Mozilla browser.

Here's my example SVG.

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
     <circle class="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

On my SASS file, I have this sample:

```
.myCircle
{
    animation: animateCircle 5s;
    
    -moz-animation: animateCircle 5s;
    -webkit-animation: animateCircle 5s;
    -ms-animation: animateCircle 5s;
}

@keyframes animateCircle 
{
    70% {
         cy: 80
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateCircle 
{
    70% {
         cy: 80
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateCircle 
{
    70% {
         cy: 80
    }
}
```

That sample code works on Chrome, but in Mozilla, it just doesn't work as expected.

Here's the [codepen:](https://codepen.io/joerben/pen/poZVOaY)
It's working on chrome but in mozilla, it doesn't even move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, values other than 0 must have units. I'm afraid you've found a Chrome bug as the Firefox implementation is correct.

All that moz and webkit stuff isn't needed any more either.

```css
.myCircle
{
    animation: animateCircle 5s;
}

@keyframes animateCircle 
{
    70% {
         cy: 80px
    }
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
     <circle class="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```